# Batch-normalization back propagation equation

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, batch-normalization

I have been trying to understand applying the back propagation on [batch-normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf). However, the matrix multiplication and equations involved have got me confused and I feel that my understanding of the forward pass itself is mistaken.

To highlight my understanding on the batch normalization forward pass and backward pass, I have written the equations in an IPython Notebook available [here](https://github.com/codeahead14/DeepLearning/blob/master/Batch%20Normalization%20-%20Equations.ipynb).

In the notebook I have explained the corresponding matrix multiplications and output-dimension and the point where mu understanding is not aligned with that explained in the paper.